# linking files with g++

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++

I have 3 files to compile:

```
main.cc
transcoder.hpp
transcoder.cc
```

The g++ commands I'm running are:

```
g++ -c -Wall -g transcoder.cc transcoder.hpp -I. -lboost_system -pthread
g++ -c -Wall -g main.cc -I. -lboost_system -pthread
g++ -o main main.o transcoder.o -I. -lboost_system -pthread
```

After the last line, I get an undefined error reference error for when code in main.cc tries to call a function defined in transcoder.hpp/transcoder.cc. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Edit to add code snippets:

transcoder.hpp

```
#include <boost/network/protocol/http/server.hpp>

namespace transcoder {

template<class T>
class Transcoder {
 public:
  void HandleRequest(const typename ::boost::network::http::server<T>::request& request,
                     typename ::boost::network::http::server<T>::response* response);
};

}  // namespace transcoder
```

transcoder.cc

```
namespace transcoder {
  using boost::network::http::server;

  template<class T>
  void Transcoder<T>::HandleRequest(const typename server<T>::request& request,
                            typename server<T>::response* response) {
    // random implementation
 }
}  // namespace transcoder
```

main.cc

```
const server<Handler>::request request;
server<Handler>::response response
::transcoder::Transcoder<Handler> transcoder;
transcoder.HandleRequest(request, &response);
```

Exact error message:

```
main.o: In function `(anonymous namespace)::Handler::operator()(boost::network::http::basic_request<boost::network::http::tags::http_server> const&, boost::network::http::basic_response<boost::network::http::tags::http_server>&)':
/some_dir/main.cc:16: undefined reference to `transcoder::Transcoder<(anonymous namespace)::Handler>::HandleRequest(boost::network::http::basic_request<boost::network::http::tags::http_server> const&, boost::network::http::basic_response<boost::network::http::tags::http_server>*)'
```

Comment: Change the order of `main.o` and `transcoder.o`.

Comment: Switching the order did nothing :s

Comment: Can you show the relevant code snippets with declaration, definition and call of the function in question and the exact error message you get.

Comment: Added code snippets and exact error :)

Comment: @n.m. was faster to mark that duplicate than me now ;)

Comment: @n.m, can you tell me what this question is a duplicate of so I can solve my problem? Edit: nvm see it on the top of the post

Comment: @n.m, I do not understand how this is a duplicate. I've declared the template in my header file. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You need to **define** it in the header, not just declare. Read the answers carefully!

Comment: I see. Thank you!